# Регулярное выражение: символ переноса строки игнорируется

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Требуется найти число в конце текста. Используется регулярное выражение `/\d+\Z/`

```
test = "123knh8y78hah099ajs980"
test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
 => ["980"]
```

Регулярное выражение работает корректно. Но если добавить "\n" в конец текста, то:

```
test = "123knh8y78hah099ajs980\n"
test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
 => ["980"]
```

Ничего не меняется, символ переноса строки игнорируется, хотя по условию нужно считать, что число не в конце текста.

Как составить регулярное выражение для решения этой проблемы? Нужно не игнорировать не только символ переноса на новую строку, но и символы табуляции и любые другие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле как можно проследить `$` скорее близок к `\Z`, зри документацию на [`RegExp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

> $ - Matches end of line
>
> \Z - Matches end of string. If string ends with a newline, it matches just before newline
>
> \z - Matches end of string

т.о. использовать нужно `\z`:

```
test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
# => ["980"] 

test.scan(/\d+$/)
# => ["980"] 

test.scan(/\d+\z/)
# => ["980"]
```

и с новою строкою:

```
test = "123knh8y78hah099ajs980\n"
test.scan(/\d+\z/)
# => [] 

test.scan(/\d+$/)
# => ["980"] 

test.scan(/\d+\Z/)
# => ["980"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`\Z` — конец данных либо позиция перед последним переводом строки (независимо от многострочного режима).

Вам нужно использовать `$` — конец данных или до завершения строки (или окончание строки в многострочном режиме).

```
/\d+$/
```

Comment: Не работает ваш вариант.

Comment: Да. Возможно. Тогда, как вариант, можно просто обрезать пробельные символы в конце строки и после этого искать совпадение.

Comment: Почему возможно, потому что это зависит от того, как интерпретируются строки: экранирующие последовательности в них. Но в общем, по-моему, само проще и наглядней — это всегда обрезать пробельные символы по краям, если они не нужны, а затем уж искать совпадения; чтобы не забивать шаблон ... Хотя, может и проще, и правильней сделать так, как сказал **Малъ Скрылевъ**.